# MatSort with dynamic columns (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

**The problem**
I have a mat-table with dynamic columns that can be added and removed, they have sort headers that should be able to sort the data. On click they don't do a thing.

**Code**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngIf="column !== 'selection'">
    <th class="cell-header" mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
    <td class="template-cell" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}}
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

This code is simple and uses an array called columns that is nothing more than a string[] that gets updated every so often. If it does, I recall the `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data)` and `this.datasource.mat = this.sort`, so I don't think that should be a problem.
In different posts people talk about using variables split by '.' but in this case I can't use that.
I understand that the columnDef and the variable used in the matCell need to be the same... but how do I do that here? Or do I have to sort with some custom function to get this working?

Comment: It seems all good, have you tried to force the re-render of the UI component? Material UI always use the `OnPush` strategy as far as I can remember. I believe that manually triggering its inner detection wont work (IE: using a `viewChild` to trigger the changes). Could please try to wrap the entire table in an `ngIf` that is toggled bt the `columns` changes?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi, that doesn't seem to do it sadly. (Updated question with answer to your question)

Answer (score 1):

I have found two ways where this frustrating problem can happen, both of which are outside the code you've provided.  (And worst of all--usually just fail silently rather than providing you a hint at what is wrong.)

1. In the module where this component is located, you must add `MatSortModule` to the imports.  If you fail to do this, the `matSort` directive in your table will usually just be ignored.
2. If you remembered to do that, you probably have an `*ngIf` directive on your table or one of its parents.  If you are following the typical example code, this will cause your `ViewChild(MatSort)` field to be undefined, so where you assign `this.datasource.mat = this.sort`, nothing is actually happening.  Trying to work around this can be decently complicated, since you'd need to set the data that triggers then ngIf, *then* wait for the change detection to rerender the component, *then* find and set the sort component.

I personally have had better luck just avoiding `*ngIf` entirely when data tables are involved, and replacing it with something like this:

```
<div
    class="table-container"
    [ngStyle]="{ display: shouldDisplay ? 'block' : 'none' }"
>
```

That way all the components will be present from the first render, and `this.sort` will bind the way you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran in to this issue as well. To fix it I used a custom function for `MatTableDataSource.sortingDataAccessor`. In my case my columns were a complex object and `[matColumnDef]` didn't match `mat-cell`, similar to what you are describing.

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (data, sortheader: string) => {
        // sortHeader will be the value of [matColumnDef] and you can 
       // do what ever logic necessary with it to return the value(s) 
      // you want sorted from your data object for the given sortheader

        return data[sortHeader];
}
```